# handling keyboard overlappingin swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

What is the best way to fix keyboard overlapping without frameworks like IQKeyboardManagerSwift or IHKeyboardAvoiding?

Comment: What is the problem? is it that the keyboard appears and covers the textfield(s)?

Comment: the keyboard appears and hide the textfield (overlapping)

Comment: Why you dont want use iqkeyboard .if pods are not working then add required classes manually . Other ways needs much changes.

Comment: I want to use the pods, but these libraries are not working they still hide the textfield idk why

Comment: I have found it that the best way to handle keyboard overlapping issue is to embed all the view in static table view controller\ and the system automatically will move up the keyboard by itself. If you don't like this way, go for IQKeyboardManager pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your scrollview bottom layout constraint,

This makes all textfields available by scrolling and you don't need to think about other devices and keyboard height differences.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

 open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

         notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        mainScrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        mainScrollViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    }
```

EDIT: I made a video about my solution.
https://youtu.be/gS4AKcJAg3Y

Comment: what do you mean with "Set your scrollview bottom layout constraint" and do I have to use this code for all controllers I need to fix my problem?

Comment: @Johnie, I've made a video you can watch and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: This is an outdated answer as of Swift 5

Answer (score 1):

The best way is, set a top constraint for your view and animate the view using constraint when click in your UITextfield.

```
@IBOutlet var constraintViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Animate the view up in "textFieldDidBeginEditing' delegate.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField {
    case yourTextfield:
        //This is the code for view up
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45, animations: {
            self. constraintViewTop.constant = -172
        })
    default:
        //This the code for view down
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.45, animations: {
            self. constraintViewTop.constant = 0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution is not robust, it will break on different devices because of the static height value, try using keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide and make use of the keyboard height instead.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the best way to handle keyboard overlapping issues, just embed(implement) all the view and textfields in the static table view controller and the system automatically will move up the keyboard by itself. If you don't like this way, go for IQKeyboardManager pod.

Comment: IQKeyboardManager is very good i do agree if you dont mind dependencies, but  about the tableView solution, imagine if my scene will only contain a textField, it's not going to be efficient to instantiate a whole tableView for only a textField.

Comment: What do you mean "to instantiate a whole tableView"? You mean it will not scroll?

Comment: i mean that implementing and entire tableView is costy for only one view